# How to merge two separate ARWorldMaps into bigger one?

Tags: swift, arkit, arworldmap

I have two `ARWorldMaps` captured onto two iOS devices and then sent to server. These maps have similar tracked areas but also have different ones. Both maps are stored on remote server. It should be noted that there's no multiuser experience in my AR app.

```
fileprivate func retrieveWorldMap() {

    let storedData = UserDefaults.standard

    if let data = storedData.data(forKey: "WorldMap") {
        
        if let unarchiver = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
                             ofClasses: [ARWorldMap.classForKeyedUnarchiver()],
                                  from: data),
            let worldMap = unarchiver as? ARWorldMap {

            config.initialWorldMap = worldMap
            sceneView.session.run(config, options: [])
        }
    }
}
```

How to merge two ARWorldMaps into bigger one, without help of a MultipeerConnectivity?